# Can I connect to freenode via SSL on Pidgin/Windows?

Tags: windows, ssl, certificate, pidgin, freenode

When I set up an IRC account on the `irc.freenode.net` server and select "Use SSL" under the advanced tab, I get an "SSL Handshake Failed" error.

I found [a guide for setting up an SSL freenode connection via Pidgin/Ubuntu](https://ubuntu-tutorials.com/2010/01/30/accessing-freenode-irc-network-via-ssl-secure-connection/) that relies on the `ca-certificates` Ubuntu package.

How can I add freenode's certificate to Pidgin on Windows? (Or otherwise set up an SSL-based account?)

Comment: first step https://superuser.com/questions/217719/what-are-the-windows-system-certificate-stores

Comment: as of this posting there is no documentation to speak of on freenode.net itself: https://blog.freenode.net/2016/02/recent-events-and-future-changes/

Comment: opened `mmc.exe` and added Certificates snap-in ... next step: get the freenode certificate in a format I can import

Comment: look like it one would expect it to be published somewhere secure by freenode - example from another server: http://wiki.chat4all.org/index.php/SSL_CA_import_instructions

Comment: looks like new website should be up soon: https://github.com/freenode/web-7.0/blob/master/content/kb/connect/chat.md

Comment: https://freenode.net/kb/answer/chat#accessing-freenode-via-ssl